# Using single vim instance with --remote-silent

Tags: vim, single-instance

I've always been a console vim user, but lately I've tried to use gvim.
I've made settings such that my console habits won't suffer, such as
opening an urxvt terminal at the current directory with .

However having multiple gvims and terminals open with my netbook is
horrible, quickly reducing my vim-space to a centimeter or two. At best,
the window width is halved, making it impossible to vertically split
screen (tiling wm).

I went around this problem by aliasing vim to `gvim --remote-silent` and it
worked fine for a couple of days, but today I needed to use -c '' and
realized that having any switches behind --remote-silent opens those
switches as files. So doing `gvim --remote-silent --foo bar` opens two
files, --foo and bar.

I put a new alias for `alias vim=gvim`, but I'm afraid this will make me a
console vim user again, sooner than I thought I would.

So the question is, what would be the preferred way to keep using gvim,
with minimal effort (setting up the system can be laborous) so that I can
still keep using vim with its full power. The solution does not need to use
remote vim, it should just minimize the gvim windows.

Comment: Can I ask why you switched to gvim if vim does what you want?

Comment: I don't understand why opening multiple instances of gvim and terminal should reduce the space for it. Bear in mind you can also use multiple tabs in an instance of Vim or gVim.

Comment: nate, gvim does some things better, some worse. For example with the same font the unicode lambda symbol is shown as lambda on gvim, and as some weird symbol on urxvt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm late coming to this party, but I have a suggestion.

First, I agree with @Herbert - there's usually very little reason to ever run more than one Vim instance (console or otherwise).  The advantages of keeping things in one instance is just too great.  But, I see the need to mix in `-c`; although I can't see the need to do it myself :D.

The best way I can see to get this functionality is to use the `--remote-send` feature of vim instead of `--remote-silent`.  This means a bit of shell scripting, however:

```
#!/bin/bash

function resolveFile
{
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        echo $(readlink -f "$1")
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

function gg
{
    local opts=$(getopt -o c: --long command: -n "gg" -- "$@")
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then return 1; fi
    eval set -- "$opts"
    cmd=""
    while :
    do
        case "$1" in
            -c|--command)
                cmd="$2"
                shift 2
                ;;
            --) shift
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done

    if [[ -n "$cmd" ]]; then
        if [[ -n "${1-}" ]]; then
            cmd=":e $(resolveFile $1)<cr>$cmd<cr>"
        else
            cmd="$cmd<cr>"
        fi
        shift 1
    fi
    files=""
    for f in $@
    do
        files="$files $(resolveFile $f)"
    done
    cmd="$cmd:args! $files<cr>"
    gvim --remote-send "$cmd"
}
```

I've only marginally tested that, but you *should* be able to do things like:

```
gg -c G file1 file2 file3 file4
```

That should *edit* `file1` and move to the bottom of it.  It should then also add `file2`, `file3` and `file4` to the args list so that you can perform commands such as `:bnext`.  It should also revert to the same sort of functionality as `--remote-silent` when you don't supply a `-c`.

I *really* think it's worth jumping through these hoops in order to properly integrate your command-line experience with a single Vim instance.  Having everything in one place is just too sweet to give up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think having multiple gvim instances running is a decent solution.  Why not just have one alias to `gvim --remote-silent` that you use when you you don't need extra switches (presumably most of the time), and another alias to just `gvim` for when you want to add command-line switches?  Seems fine to me, not much extra to remember.

The main unpleasantness from having multiple gvim instances running, aside from getting many windows that are hard to keep track of, is that each gvim has its own runtime envioronment, harder to share and copy data between buffers in different gvim instances.

Derek Wyatt has interesting video on --remote-silent; I don't think it addresses your issue but you may be interested in watching it: 
[OneVimToRuleThemAll](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-intermediate-tutorial-videos/#onevim)

Also, if problem is that window splits within gvim are taking screen estate away, make better use of the tab functionality (you can even disable the actual tab labels but keep metaphor of open tab pages) and/or alternatively just navigate between buffers while having only one buffer visible at a time.

Comment: I think OP is not complaining about window splits *within* GVim; rather, opening multiple windows causes their tiling window manager to split the multiple X windows, to the point where GVim becomes unusably small.

Comment: Exactly. Two vims side by side is with my font size around 70-100 characters, any less and it's unusable